# How to change the camera used for render?

Tags: rendering, camera

I have 2 cameras in my scene, and want to use one for rendering an animation. Despite defining it as the active camera and playing with the "lock" camera to view button, my render is still made from the first camera, with different render settings than the ones I have set?

Any thoughts one where the problem might come from?

[image: tried to make it clear]

Here is the .blend file if anyone is willing to give it a look : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26579

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have an image strip in the *Video Sequence Editor*, so pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> renders from the strip rather than from the scene.

Remove the image strip or disable *Sequencer* in *Properties > Render settings > Post Processing* to render from the scene.

[image]